# Why is the code on jsfiddle.net not working in jsbin.com?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I make my own language using codemirror, what I want to do when I stop on name of function and hover on it or press on (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to show tooltip display the type and other data for this function, the code run on jsfiddle.net but not run on  jsbin.com

```
 var cm = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("editor"), {
    value: "function myScript() {\n    return 100;\n}",

    indentUnit: 4,
    lineNumbers: true
});

var textMarker;

$('#add').click(function() {
    textMarker = cm.markText({
        line: 1,
        ch: 4
    }, {
        line: 1,
        ch: 10
    }, {
        className: 'marked-text'
    });

    $('.marked-text').tooltip({
        title: 'This is a return statement',
        container: 'body',
        delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 100 },
        animation: false
    });
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
    if (textMarker) {
        textMarker.clear();
    }
});
```

The link to working code: [here code works](https://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/tooaq4oc/)

My try but not work: [my try](http://jsbin.com/jemapovira/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding libraries under "external resources" from jsfiddle to jsbin.

Edit:
Yes you're right you added the libraries. I made it work putting JQuery as the first `script` since you can't load bootstrap before JQuery. Then change the `http` to `https`.

Comment: plz see the code , I add libraries under "external resources" from jsfiddle to jsbin before I ask @ván Rodríguez Torres

Comment: ok it work after your change thank you @Iván Rodríguez Torres

Comment: why the tooltip in jsbin not look good like in jsfiddle ?@Iván Rodríguez Torres

Comment: I let you the link that is working. http://jsbin.com/nosaze/edit?html,js,output 
Now I think that the problem is that bootstrap is not loading properly, but I can't make sure. Note that I add some extra CSS to make the tooltip visible

Comment: Glad I helped!!